# Search by product tags?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

I want to adapt the mini search to search for product tags rather than name.

Which files and code will I need to change to achieve this?

Comment: trying to unerstand, you want to remove the name search or want to keep name search as well with tag searching?

Comment: Would like to keep the name and add the tags too